# Remove ns0 and ns1 prefix and include a new prefix in all tags with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I need help to create a XSLT mapping, for remove all prefix ns  (NS0 , NS1, etc) and include a new prefix in all tags.

Below the XML de input and output for examplification.

Input

```
<ns0:ExecuteMultipleOperations xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com">
    <ns0:Operations>
        <ns0:Operation>
            <ns0:Action>Create</ns0:Action>
            <ns0:Object>
                <ns1:SOUser xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com">
                    <ns1:FullName>My Full Name</ns1:FullName>
                    <ns1:EmailAddress>name@fake.mail</ns1:EmailAddress>
                    <ns1:Active>1</ns1:Active>
                </ns1:SOUser>
            </ns0:Object>
        </ns0:Operation>
    </ns0:Operations>
    <ns0:OneTransaction>true</ns0:OneTransaction>
    <ns0:ContinueOnError>true</ns0:ContinueOnError>
</ns0:ExecuteMultipleOperations>
```

Output

```
<clic:ExecuteMultipleOperations xmlns:clic="http://www.example.com">
    <clic:Operations>
        <clic:Operation>
            <clic:Action>Create</clic:Action>
            <clic:Object>
                <clic:SOUser>           
                    <clic:FullName>My Full Name</clic:FullName>
                    <clic:EmailAddress>name@fake.mail</clic:EmailAddress>
                    <clic:Active>1</clic:Active>
                </clic:SOUser>
            </clic:Object>
        </clic:Operation>
    </clic:Operations>
    <clic:OneTransaction>true</clic:OneTransaction>
    <clic:ContinueOnError>true</clic:ContinueOnError>
</clic:ExecuteMultipleOperations>
```

Any sugestion ?

Comment: **Caution: **consider why you care about the namespace prefix. If it's because you just want it to look consistent, that's fine, but if it's because something is breaking and doesn't work right unless the `clic` prefix is used, that is a smell. It is likely that they are doing some sort of hacky string-parsing, rather than using XML tools and APIs that would identify the elements that the namespace that they are bound to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below XSLT that matches all the elements having prefix `ns0` and `ns1` and replaces their names with `clic` prefix.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:clic="http://www.example.com" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

     <xsl:template match="ns0:* | ns1:*">
        <xsl:element name="clic:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<clic:ExecuteMultipleOperations xmlns:clic="http://www.example.com">
    <clic:Operations>
        <clic:Operation>
            <clic:Action>Create</clic:Action>
            <clic:Object>
                <clic:SOUser>
                    <clic:FullName>My Full Name</clic:FullName>
                    <clic:EmailAddress>name@fake.mail</clic:EmailAddress>
                    <clic:Active>1</clic:Active>
                </clic:SOUser>
            </clic:Object>
        </clic:Operation>
    </clic:Operations>
    <clic:OneTransaction>true</clic:OneTransaction>
    <clic:ContinueOnError>true</clic:ContinueOnError>
</clic:ExecuteMultipleOperations>
```

Comment: Note that XSLT 1.0 does not guarantee that the output of this stylesheet will use the prefix "clic", though it's likely that many XSLT 1.0 processors will deliver the desired result. XSLT 2.0 does guarantee that the prefix "clic" will be used.